# Push data when SQL is updated

Tags: javascript, pusher

I want to setup a javascript listener that automatically knows when the SQL database is updated.

I am using Pusher (web service) to receive real time notification.

I am not 100% sure of how I should make this work but here is my plan:

1. Set a cron job every 10 seconds to check if the database has been updated
2. If yes, then send the data to the Pusher server
3. I set a pusher listener in JavaScript on all clients
4. When data is sent to Pusher server, the server send the data to all clients and the data is updated

Heres a diagram of that:

[image: diagram]

Does that make sense? Is it a good idea to use a cron job on the server to check if the data has been updated or?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a messaging queue or PubSub in redis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that makes sense. (And thanks for the diagram.)

Know that your updates will be up to 10 seconds after the update, plus whatever Pusher's latency is.

There are two other possibilities:

- **Application level** Whenever your server issues a query to update this, notify Pusher.
- **Database level** Use a database trigger to kick off the request to Pusher. The details of this approach depend on your DBMS.

Triggers can be a little icky, so do it in your application server if possible.

Comment: Thanks Paul! Where can I learn more about database trigger? Can this be setup direcly in the DB?

Comment: @PeterLur, I said, it will depend on your database (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostreSQL, SQLite, etc.) for exactly how database triggers work, and also how you can get SQL to talk to "the outside world".